# It is true that $2\sin(54)$ equals $(1+\sqrt5)/2$?

Tags: number-theory

From a popular math site I saw the formula of phi number which is $2 \sin(54^\circ )$. But we also know it is $(1+\sqrt5)/2$ . With calculator this equation has problems. Do you think $2\sin(54)$ is just approximation?
By the way is $\sin(54^\circ)$ irrational?

Comment: No, it is not an approximation, we indeed have: $$2\sin (54^{\circ})=\varphi $$ and yes, it is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you find it
[image]

[image]

now you can apply the $sin(3x)$ formula $3*sin(x)-4(sinx)^3$

yes, $sin(54)$ is irrational.

proof:

$sin(54)=(1+\sqrt5)/4$
thus $\sqrt5$=$4*sin(54)-1$

as you know that $\sqrt5$ is irrational

also 1 is rational

thus $4*sin(54)$ has to be irrational

4 is rational and sin(54) is irrational

Comment: Sorry, your images cannot be opened. But when I try to subtract one from the other, it must be 0, calculator says it is 2,58599e-39

Comment: it is because the calculators represent and store the numbers as floating point

Comment: there is always some error because we can not  take the infinite length of mantissa in floating point representation this leads to error

Comment: I am not sure why images are not opening it is either the fault of your internet connection or stack exchange  try opening them in laptop or pc if you have one

Comment: I just learned our government has denied imgur, also wiki, anyway.

Comment: see this site this might help you  http://www.math-only-math.com/exact-value-of-sin-54-degree.html

my solution is almost same as shown on this site